# What does 'handle an event' mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a problem when I'm reading iOS's document for [Event Types and Delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW1). For this:

> If the first responder or the hit-test view doesn’t handle an event

What does 'handle an event' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle an event means that there is a method that is called when the event is fired.  For instance, if you click on a button and there is a method that is called when that button is clicked, that acts in response to the button, then it handles the event.

Comment: Thanks! You help me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

user is right. To add on, to NOT handle an event is when you send a event that is not able to execute whatever method properly. For example, take the button again. Say you pressed it, but you assigned it's action to a method that throws an exception. The button didn't handle the event. Also, if you assign a button to an IBAction, but forget to code the action, then the button can not handle the event.

Handling an event just means that an action executes it's assigned method correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Because I can't accept two answer at the same time. I just give you a up vote.